# EGL create iframe in handler

Tags: iframe, egl, rich-ui

I use egl rich ui. I have a handler and i try to add an iframe in this. I found a code example but this does't work. What's going wrong following code?

```
handler Test type RUIhandler{initialUI =[ui], onConstructionFunction = start, cssFile = "css/test.css", title = "Test"}

ui Div{padding = 10, children =[Box, BoxDataGrid, iframe]};

iframe Widget{tagName = "iframe", width = "500", height="100"};
 function start()
    iframe.setAttribute("src", "http://www.google.gr");
end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe was the url. Google is prohibiting using its site inside an iframe. The folownig code works.

```
handler test5 type RUIhandler {initialUI = [ iframe ],onConstructionFunction = start, cssFile="css/frommclient.css", title="test5"}



iframe Widget{tagName = "iframe", width = "500", height="100"};
 function start()
    iframe.setAttribute("src", "http://www.frommedv.de");
end

end
```